# How to know if a bounding box(rectangle) lies inside another bounding box(rectangle)?

Tags: python, opencv, bounding-box

I am trying to get the boxes(co-ordinates) inside the outer box. I have done using the intersection over union method and I want other methods to do so.[image]

Also, can you please tell me how to compare those two inner boxes?

Comment: I don't understand your problem... if you have already used intersection... what is the matter now ?

Comment: @KevinNguetchouang i wanted other ways to do it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By comparing the coordinates of the top-left and bottom-right corners of the bounding box and the inner boxes it is easy to know if any of the latter is inside the former.

The following code is a simple example with only one bounding box and one inner box:

```py
# Bounding box
boundb = {
    'x': 150,
    'y': 150,
    'height': 50,
    'width': 100
}

# Inner box
innerb = {
    'x': 160,
    'y': 160,
    'height': 25,
    'width': 25
}

# If top-left inner box corner is inside the bounding box
if boundb['x'] < innerb['x'] and boundb['y'] < innerb['y']:
    # If bottom-right inner box corner is inside the bounding box
    if innerb['x'] + innerb['width'] < boundb['x'] + boundb['width'] \
            and innerb['y'] + innerb['height'] < boundb['y'] + boundb['height']:
        print('The entire box is inside the bounding box.')
    else:
        print('Some part of the box is outside the bounding box.')
```